# Fixed acceleration for jQuery easing?

Tags: jquery

I am making an unconventional website that scrolls horizontally for VERY large distances. I've noticed that jQuery's easing functions get stretched out over the span of the length of the scrolled distance. The duration for which it accelerates seems to be a fixed fraction of the distance it needs to scroll. For example, it may accelerate for the first 1/5th of the distance, scroll at a constant rate for 3/5th and then decelerate for the remaining 1/5th. This makes the acceleration more sluggish when scrolling long distances. Any way to make it accelerate for a fixed amount of time no matter the distance it needs to scroll?

Here's part of my code if it helps

```
$('tbody.travelTo a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollLeft: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().left - 1/2 * $(window).width() + 1/2 * $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).width()
    }, $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().left / travelRate, 'swing');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the duration in the `animate` method. [API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Something like this

```
.animate( 
   {scrollTop:'300px'},
   300, //duration is the 2nd parameter (default - 400ms)
   swing,
   function(){ 
     alert(animation complete! - your custom code here!); 
   } 
)
```

Or you can always write your own easing methog

```
jQuery.easing.method(   
 null,  
 current_time,  
 start_value,   
 end_value,     
 total_time 
)
```

Useful links - http://forrst.com/posts/How_to_create_custom_jQuery_easing_functions-OKb

Comment: I am able to set the duration of the entire scrolling event, but I want to set the duration of the acceleration portion of the scrolling event. Think of it this way, right now if the screen has to scroll 100px over 5 seconds it might do something like this:

Comment: accelerate: 1 second  
constant speed: 3 seconds  
decelerate: 1 second  

If it has to scroll 500px it might do this:  

accelerate: 5 seconds  
constant speed: 15 seconds  
decelerate: 5 seconds  

But what I want it to do is this:  

accelerate: 1 second  
constant speed: 23 seconds  
decelerate: 1 second  

Do you see how it kept a constant acceleration duration when compared to the first distance (100px)?

Comment: I think, the effect is due the type of easing you have selected.

Comment: yeah, I've looked at all those graphs. it doesn't matter which one I choose. The graph gets "stretched" out across the distance I ask it to scroll

Comment: looks like you require a custom easing function, look at my update answer

Comment: The Useful link you provided in your updated answer is very interesting. It looks like it is the solution to my problem, that being said, I'm not mathematically inclined enough to create the equations for my custom easing functions. The best I have come up with is the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/dfjosh/naXBa/

but it is far from what I actually want